# Automatically disable nightshift when connected to external monitor

Tags: display, night-shift

I'm trying to automatically disable night shift when I have an external monitor connected via HDMI to my MBA. Then re-enable when I disconnect from the external monitor.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this that are automated?

MacBook Air (M2, 2022)
MacOS 12.5 (21G72)